# Java: Nested classes, interfaces Vs Package

Tags: java

I was reading nested classes will enable group classes & interfaces logically.

I feel this we can achieve using package as well by placing related classes in a package.

If this is the case, where exactly the Nested class and Nested interface come into play? When should we consider using them?

Comment: Think this is primarily opinion based, but I use a nested class like one would use a C++ struct. Just as a temporary holder for data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one main thing that you can do with [nested classes/interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), that you cannot do with packages: You can have types that are *private* to a specific class. Standalone interfaces and classes can only be public or have the default (package-wide) visibility. This can be quite helpful if you wish to limit the access to the internals of an implementation.

In addition, non-static nested classes will contain an implicit reference to the parent object. This reduces the amount of code that you need to write - no need for parameterized `new MyObject(this)` constructor calls - although it may also increase the size of a type inadvertently if the parent object field is not used.

I would say that to a degree the use of inner classes is a matter of design and personal preference. For example, in my own projects I often choose to split-off an inner type to a separate file when its code becomes too large for my tastes. In public objects, however, the need to *hide* the details of an implementation may be more important.

PS: By the way, the Java compiler creates a separate [class file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) for each type anyway - from the POV of the JVM whatever you do is mostly the same...

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a grouping.

```
class Container {
    public class Item {
         ... can use Container.this to access its container.
    }
    private List<Item> items = ...;

    public Item createNewItem() {
        Item item = new Item();
        items.add(item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

The interesting design offers to every Item the access to the Container it is in.

The same mechanism is used in standard java SE with **Iterator** implementations. The implementation class often is an embedded class of the collection, thus having access to it.

*I do not know the context of your citation, but that might be what was meant.*

This pattern allows access to private members of the containing class, and the alternative would need an extra constructor argument to maintain a link to the containing object.

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes (that are not static) have access to instance fields of the outer class that non-nested classes wouldn't have.

You can declare a nested class or interface to be `private`.  This is useful when the *implementation* of a class benefits from defining other classes or interfaces; since the class or interface is an implementation detail, it should be hidden from clients that use the outer class.  You can't do this if the class or interface is at the top level.  (You can make it package-private, but it will still be visible to other classes in the same package, which may not be desirable.  I think it depends on how tightly the implementation of the nested class is coupled to the implementation of the outer class.  If the code in the nested class doesn't make sense independently of the code in the outer class, then it should probably be nested.)

Other than those, it's a choice of how to name things.  In Android, many classes that extend `View` have their own nested `LayoutParams` classes (over a dozen of them).  I suppose they could have put all those classes at the top level and given them names like `AbsListViewLayoutParams`, `TableRowLayoutParams`, etc. (instead of `AbsListView.LayoutParams`, etc.), but the actual choice makes it clear that these are classes with similar purposes that are closely related to their "parent" classes.  Setting up 17 packages or so to group those related classes together could have caused some other problems (perhaps they would no longer be able to access package-private members of other classes that they needed), and seems obnoxious even if it doesn't create this kind of problem.